# TFS 2005 on w2k3 x64?

Tags: tfs, 64-bit

Just a quicky anyone point me to any articles on getting TFS on w2k3 x64 working or if it's possible as it appears not to be =<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application tier of Team Foundation Server cannot be installed on a 64-bit environment.

It caught me out a couple of months ago when I forgot this fact:

https://blog.iannelson.uk/on-64-bit-tfs-virtualization-and-conchango-scrum/

Comment: Yup.  TFS is currently not supported on a 64-bit OS.  Support for 64-bit on the server is scheduled for TFS 2010.